# Where to store github token in public repository

Tags: github

My application calls GitHub API so I have to store GitHub token somewhere. I don't want to publish my token to public repository. I decided to store it in environmental variables. Disadvantage of environmental variables is that I have to set it correctly on all machines (localhost, codenvy, jenkins ...) 
Is there better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily move it to [Properties file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) and distribute it on all systems you need. If the security is matter for you, consider encryption of actual values for such file.

Hope it helps!

Comment: To encrypt values in property file? The algorithm of decryption would be in application, but application is public at all, so anybody can see secrets and simulate decryption by own.

Comment: It's really depends on your algorithm and sensitivity of the data you want to secure. In real environment you can restrict access to file using OS or supply secret (indirect) key to your software.